# Format 'Detail' background of report, based on content of table field?

Tags: vba, ms-access, format, case, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to color the background of a record's detail section on a report, different colors depending on the person the record's linked to.  this is what I've gotten so far, but it doesn't work. Access says "can't find field 'person'":

```
Private Sub Detail_Format()

Select Case Me!Color
    Case "Red"
        Me!Detail.BackColor = vbRed
    Case "Blue"
        Me!Detail.BackColor = vbBlue
    Case "Green"
        Me.Detail.BackColor = vbGreen
    Case "Yellow"
        Me.Detail.BackColor = vbYellow
End Select

End Sub
```

Since there's several records on a page I'm trying to get it so all the 'Red' records on a page have a red background, all the 'Blue' records have a blue background, etc. so a page of the report would look something like:

Red
Blue
Red
Green
Yellow
Yellow
Blue

and so forth, each one a different record assigned to that color's person.

The report has various fields (Name, Age, Position, Notes, etc), but the 'Color' field is in the table with the others and NOT used in the report itself, only the other fields in the table are.

So, is it possible to color code a report like that, based on a record's field that's not used in the report itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty certain Color is a reserved word, which may be confusing the issue.

That aside, in a report unlike a form, the field has to be in the reports data, and available on the report even if hidden. I would give it an alias of txtColor in the reports underlying query and put it in the detail section in a hidden control.

You should then be able to refer to it in the detail format event.

Comment: That ALMOST did it!  I broke the 'details' section up, and put some of the fields in the 'details header' section, looks less cluttered that way- and duplicated the coloring code to handle both 'Detail.BackColor' and 'DetailHeader.BackColor'.  But for some reason, DetailHeader is being colored the same as the *previous* record, not the record it belongs to.

Comment: Other than that, though, it's working great, thank you!  But any ideas on how to fix that problem?

Comment: Have you put the colour field in the detail header or the detail? If it's only in the detail the I don't think the header will "see" it.

Comment: That last comment did it, thank you very much!  It works perfectly :)